# Multichannel communication with Arduino and HC-12 transmitter

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, communication

The HC-12 module has 100 possible channels starting at 433 MHz. Can someone tell me how to program the Arduino to use multiple channels at the same time? My goal is to build an RC transmitter with Arduino and an HC-12 module for a quadcopter. Therefore I need 6 channels, like a normal transmitter does. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are misunderstanding what it means by channels. The HC-12 can transmit on up to 100 channels, which means different frequencies under the 433 MHz band. For example 433.05 MHz or 433.15 MHz. This is so multiple HC-12 modules can be used next to each other and only the module receiving on the channel of the transmitter will receive the data broadcast.

What you need to do for your quadcopter is send an array of bytes that begins with a constant, followed by the data you need (a packet). Example:

```
byte packet[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01}

// in your loop
packet[1] = ; HOW MUCH THE ENGINE IS THROTTLED
packet[2] = ; HOW FAR THE CONTROL TO GO FORWARD IS DEPRESSED
// etc
```

Iterate through this array writing the data through the serial port to the HC-12. Whenever your receiver detects the constant (in this case 0x00) read the values that follow as the controls for the quadcopter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting on HC-12 myself and as I understand, you can only access 1 module at a time by selecting each modules individual channel, assuming you have set the modules to separate channels, you cannot receive data from multiple modules even if set to the same channel at the same time, it would just be a jumble of unsortable data. But you may be able to select one channel after another and collect each set of data separately 1 thru 6 and then extract the information you need by using AT+C001,002,etc. Or you could use 1 RX and program the on board arduino to cycle thru the 6 motors sequentially and collect the 6 sets of data that way. this question would be easier to answer with a diagram of you proposed circuit.